# Update ARR and CCR1 delays function return by 6us

Tags: performance, timer, stm32, pwm

I need to vary the frequency and duty cycle of a pwm using stm32f401.
Inside the "pulse finished" pwm callback i've tried the following code

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED5_PORT, LED5_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET); 
//tentative 1
//TIM9->ARR = round(value);
//TIM9->CCR1 = round(value) * 0.2;
//tentative 2
//htim9.Instance->ARR = round(value);
//htim9.Instance->CCR1 = round(value) * 0.2;
//tentative 3
int *point = (int *) (TIM9_BASE + 0x2C);
*point = round(value);
int *point1 = (int *) (TIM9_BASE + 0x34);
*point1 = round(value) *0.2;
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED5_PORT, LED5_PIN, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

In all the 3 cases if i measure with an oscilloscope the amount of time that passes between the ON/OFF state of the LED5 the value is 6us.
The ON/OFF state alone is 500ns.
This means that i'm waiting my function to return for 5.5us just for assigning those two registers and so i'm limited in term of performance frequency.

It is clear that i have a problem which im not seeing.

Any ideas?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> *It is clear that i have a problem which im not seeing.*

Definitely - the first and the main one - the HAL library. Use bare registers instead.

Another one - you use double (not the float ones) numbers and math functions - and your FPU will not you help with it. Any calculation takes tens of the clock cycles.

So with 84MHz core, HAL & double number 5us is not bad :D

Comment: Is this HAL?

TIM9->CCR1 = round(value) * 0.2;?

even TIM9->CCR1 = 1200; leads to the same problem

Comment: I already gave you the answer. Time sensitive routines means "no HAL". More sensitive - run from SRAM, even more - split code and data between CCM & "normal" SRAM

Comment: sorry but i can't understand, to me HAL is everything which has HAL in it.

Comment: HAL means large overhead. If program is time sensitive - avoid HAL - program uC using registers. I can't help you more. - no miracles - large, "easy", buggy, slow library or more complex but efficient hardware level coding. It is your choice.

Comment: @PeterJ: HAL overhead is taken into account in the posting.

Comment: And double numbers arithmetic eg *point1 = round(value) *0.2;